# Javascript - calling functions from a third party

Tags: javascript

Why is this possibly undefined and how would I fix it?

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1 + function(){ return 10; }// This could be the wrong way to do it. But it could come from a third party, so it's undeterminded when it's returning. S
console.log(b);
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - can you provide a better example?  In the one you've given, it will simple log `"1function (){ return 10; }"`

Comment: You're taking a function (not the return value) and adding 1 to it. `1 + function` is not valid and gives you undefined. You can wrap your function in an immediately executed function instead: `1 + (function() { return 10; })();`

Comment: What does this have to do with third party functions? Where do you get undefined? I feel a lot is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that function to work you have to execute it:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1 + function(){ return 10; }()// This could be the wrong way to do it. But it could come from a third party, so it's undeterminded when it's returning. S
console.log(b);
```

Notice I added the () after the function.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call the function.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 1 + (function(){ return 10; })()
console.log(b);
```